# How to reverse a Map in dart? Is there any build in function

Tags: dart

Given a Map like `{203: 5, 201: 3, 204: 1}`, how can I reverse it, to get a result like `{204: 1,201: 3:203: 5}`? Is there a built-in function?

Comment: A map (hashmap) has no order, it is a key, value lookup - so reversing it doesn't make sense. Can you describe what problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

map.lenght should be map.length

thanks for your code

```
sort(Map map){
  Map newmap;
  for(int i =0 ; i< map.length; i++){
     String x = map.entries.last.key.toString();
     int y = map.entries.last.value;
     newmap[x] = y;
     map.remove(x);
  }
  return newmap;
}
```

Comment: Do not use the map.length in your loop declaration, because its length is decreased by the map.remove so the map is not fully iterated.

Answer (score 6):

Does this work? (I'm on mobile and can't test)

```
import 'dart:collection';

void main() {
  final m = {203: 5, 201: 3, 204: 1};
  final reverseM = LinkedHashMap.fromEntries(m.entries.toList().reversed);
  print(reverseM);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't compile.

Answer (score 3):

If someone still need a solution, I wrote a [simple library](https://pub.dev/packages/deep_collection) to deeply reverse `Map`, `Set` and `List`. Usage is simple, because `deepReverse()` is an extension method, so all you need to do is to import my library and call the method on your map:

```dart
import 'package:deep_collection/deep_collection.dart';


void main() {
  print({203: 5, 201: 3, 204: 1}.deepReverse());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this is the simplest way to reverse Map by its keys in Dart language:

```
reverseMap(Map map) {
 Map newmap = {};
  for (String _key in map.keys.toList().reversed) {
    newmap[_key] = map[_key];
   }
 return newmap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this doesn't handle the situation where values are duplicated, but if that's not an issue:

```
Map reverseMap(Map map) => {
    for (var e in map.entries) e.value: e.key};
reverseMap({'a': 1, 'b': 2})
// {1: 'a', 2: 'b'}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Map.fromEntries(styles.entries.toList().reversed);
```